# Distributivity of exponentiation over multiplication in the complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I've gotten myself quite confused over this. It's apparent that we cannot have $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{w} \quad \forall z,w \in \mathbb{C}$, since otherwise one could show $1=-1$ and such. But this also threatens the identity $(zw)^n = z^nw^n \quad \forall z,w \in \mathbb{C}, \forall n \in \mathbb{R}$, (which I have assumed to still hold in the complex numbers..) since it evidently fails for $n=\frac{1}{2}$. Is this identity actually mistaken in the complex numbers?

For perhaps more context on why this arose, it came in course of thinking of the question "Prove there exists no function $f:\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)^2=z$ and $f(zw)=f(z)f(w)$, but that many functions exist with just one of these properties". I thought I had an example of the latter with $f(z)=z^n$, for some $n\in\mathbb{R}$..!

Comment: When working over $\mathbb{C}$, you'll first need to define properly what you mean by the function you designate by the square root symbol..

Comment: The identity $z^\alpha w^\alpha = (zw)^\alpha$ holds only sometimes. It holds for all $z,w$ if $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ ($z,w\neq 0$ if $\alpha < 0$, or make provisions for dealing with $\infty$), but for $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Z}$, it only holds for some $z,w$, whichever variant of $z^\alpha$ you choose. It's a common source of errors. Also, $(z^\alpha)^\beta = z^{\alpha\beta}$ does in general not hold.